# Vue Socket.io: Client isn't receiving message from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I am building a multiplayer game using Vue and Socket.io. I am able to send data from the client to the server but it doesn't work the other way around, and I can't figure out why.

Here is some of my code:

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(4000);

// socket io
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('User connected ' + socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    console.log('User disconnected ' + this.id);
  });
  socket.on('joined-game', function(data) {
    console.log('player joined game' + this.id);
    io.emit('start-game', { game: data });
  });
});
```

in **JoinGame.vue**

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
export default {
  data() {
    return { games: "", invite: "", nickname: "", socket: io('http://localhost:4000') }
  },
  methods: {
    joinGame() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/game/' + this.invite)
        .then(response => {
          this.games = response.data;
          this.socket.emit('joined-game', { game: this.invite, nickname: this.nickname });
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

in **AddPlayer.vue**

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
export default {
  data() {
    return { invite: "", addedGame: false, waiting: true, socket: io('http://localhost:4000')  }
  },
  methods: {
    mounted() {
      this.socket.on('start-game', function (data) {
        console.log('player 2 joined game');
        if(data.game === this.invite) {
          this.waiting = false;
        }
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to emit "joined-game" from the client to the server but it looks like "start-game" isn't emitted from the server to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mounted function inside methods. Try having it outside.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: Thanks!! I can't believe I missed that aha everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody has an issue where emits aren't being received by the client,
my problem was:

I had added the socket in sockets like so:

```
    connect() {
      this.isConnected = true;
      console.log("socket hit");
    }
  },
```

This for some reason doesn't work (referred to a few tutorials and found this).

In "mounted()" I did not have anything.  I have now added:

```
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("emit received from server");
    });
  },
```

This works fine and I can see the emit.